# Which event is fired when releasing a HTML input range (slider) on touch device?

Tags: html, slider, touch

In my Angular 2 app I use a plain vanilla HTML5 input type "range" to provide the user a simple slider component.

```
<input type="range" [min]="x" [max]="y" (mouseup)="onReleased()" />
```

I need to know when the user released the slider. Releasing means that using a mouse the dragging is finished and the mouse button has been released. For that purpose I hook into the OnMouseUp event. However, this does not apply in case I use a touch device.

On my tablet I can drag the slider aroun, but when releasing it with my finger the event is no fired.

I know, this is not a mouse, but what event is equivalent to on mouse up and works on touch devices?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would appear to be the [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend) event.

I assume there is a way to make the slider a touch surface within the wider [Touch Events Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)